Using QGIS variable in .qgs file
I'm working on a routine to export layout for a scheduled activity of administrative borders analysis, so I need to set up a QGIS project to work every time with the same set of data but on different areas.
In the project I have several layers whose source is a feature ArcGIS REST service and in some cases I'm not able to download the entire dataset because of the limit set by the provider. The source is updated frequently, so it will always be my reference in terms of content even if using ESRI sources is not something I really like.
Nevertheless, I see that if I choose to download a portion of the data, limiting to the extent of the view, a bounding box is applied (I can see that from the information of the layer) and I'm able to download the features.
Given that, I created a polygon to define a custom boundary box and, via Python code in macro, I defined a project variable with the extent of my bbox in a string format, intending to use that as a part of the string that define the datasource directly in the .qgis file. I edited the .qgs file, searched for the interested rows and put the variable in the string of the datasoirce, specifically in the part related to the bbox, using the expression "bbox=@bbox [...]" without success.
Has someone ever done that successfully? I can definitely use a project defined variable in the .qgis file... Any ideas?

Is storing the REST data in a local database (like postgres) an option? - doing something similar but we pre-process REST data first then run QGIS Atlas to export 100's of maps.

Unfortunately storing locally is not an option, because data are always updating and filtering directly without going to Postgresql would save us precious time

Thanks for the answer, I edited my question. I put the variable in the .qgs, in the rows related to the layers i want to filter with the bbox, specifically in the string of the datasource.

Have you tried this solution?

Else since a qgs file is a text file, you can easily manipulate any part of it (like a small script opening the file, looking for a specific bbox placeholder, replacing it with the bbox extent, save file, (re)load it qgis)
